# Ошибка в Monodevelop при использовании MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, monodevelop

Всем привет, ребята!

Стоит вопрос о написании приложения на C# для работы с БД

Использую среду разработки Monodevelop 7.8.4

Для работы нужно импотировать пространство имен MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Начало кода выглядит так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; - вот тут выдает ошибку


Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found
```

Пробовал разрешить эту проблему по [совету](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481002/how-to-install-nuget-addin-for-monodevelop/481005#481005) путем добавления репозитория NuGet. Шаги:

```
1. Выбрал Tools далее Extension Manager
2. Выбрал Gallery далее Manage Repositories
3. Нажал Add выбрал Register an on-line repository
4. Вставил URL http://mrward.github.com/monodevelop-nuget-addin-repository/4.0/main.mrep
5. Принял
6. Открыл IDE Extensions и установил ВСЕ NuGet пакеты
7. Перезагрузил приложение
8. Перезагрузил систему
9. Провел обряд с бубном
10. Призывал духов Ада
11. Говорил с потомками Фортрана
12...
```

НО ОШИБКА СОХРАНЯЕТСЯ

Никто не сталкивался? Будьте добры советом! Спасибо!

Comment: [Установите](https://askubuntu.com/a/481005) NuGet пакет `MySql.Data`

Comment: @aepot, не помогло. Установил даже те дополнения из серии NuGet, которые не указаны по ссылке. Перезапускал MonoDevelop. Ничего не работает

Comment: Расшифруйте фразу "ничего не работает" как можно подробнее, и обновите вопрос, его можно редактировать.

Comment: @aepot, можете подсказать по вопросу?

Comment: К сожалению, нет, так как я ни то, не другое не использую.

Comment: [Руководство](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) по написанию скрипта на Python для работы с СУБД MySQL